# How do I process very large file (13GB) in python without crashing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory, memory-management

I have to process this very large file on a server (not my computer). It runs python 64 and has 24 GB of RAM. The file itself is around 13GB in size with 27 million rows of data. Considering the server has pretty big spec, I did try to load the whole to pandas, but it crashed. I tried to use dask, but it's still really slow. So I separated the file in chunks like the following.

My code is similar to this below. I load the file in chunks, where each chunk is 100,000 lines of data. Then it will process each chunk, and append it to an existing file. I thought that by processing things in chunk, it wouldn't store the data in RAM, but I think it still did. The first few hundred iterations worked fine, but sometime after it processed 8GB of data, it just crashed.

```
chunksize= 100000
c = 0
for chunk in pd.read_csv(fname, chunksize=chunksize,sep='|',error_bad_lines=False):

    chunk['col1'] = chunk['col1'].apply(process1)
    chunk['col2'] = chunk['col2'].apply(process2)

    if c == 0:
        chunk.to_csv("result/result.csv", index=False)
    else:
        chunk.to_csv('result/result.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)

    if c%10==0:
        print(c)
        
    c+=1
```

Usually after 160 iterations which resulted in 8 GB of result.csv file, the program just stopped with a `MemoryError:`.

I do not have access to many things in this sever to be honest, so if you want to suggest changing some settings that I don't have access to, then I probably cannot. But let's see what I can do. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I will add what's going on in `process1` and `process2` here.

```
def process1(name):
    if type(name)==str:
        new_name = name[:3]+'*' * len(name[:-3])
    else:
        return name
    
    return new_name

def process2(number):
    if number !=np.nan:
        new_number = str(number)
        new_number = '*'*len(new_number)
        return new_number
    else:
        return number
```

Comment: 13GB is small file in 2020...

Comment: What is `process1` and `process2`? If one of those functions is inefficient then that may be the issue.

Comment: @DavidErickson both are just functions to replace string in a certain condition. I don't think they're heavy in computation though.

Comment: @catris25 are you able to include those in your question? Those functions could be the issue.

Comment: I can't image how "heavy" would have anything to do with memory consumption. If they did something to keep an object alive, that's a different story. I guess you could do `gc.collect()` on every round to see if there is something about them that causes circular dependencies.

Comment: @DavidErickson I just added more details

Comment: @tdelaney okay, I will try that, but what does `gc.collect()` do?

Comment: @catris25 it looks like you are potentially significantly increasing the size of your string, so even if you are reading in a 13GB file if you are transforming data and each row is becoming let's say 3x longer, then you will hit a memory limitation at some point given a 24GB limit.

Comment: A circular reference happens when an object references itself either directly (e.g., its a list that includes itself) or indirectly (e.g., a node has a back link to the node behind it). It will still have a reference count even after it can't be reached by any python variable. The garbage collection module `gc` has a function `collect` that finds them and deletes them ... at leas in theory.

Comment: Looking at your update, I don't see a circular reference there.

Comment: Put a `del chunk` after you've written the CSV. In the `for`, a new dataframe is created and then assigned to `chunk`. In that period, both the old and new chunk are in memory at the same time. Do the `del` at the end of the chunk and you won't have that overlap.

Comment: @tdelaney okay I will. Should I still include the `gc.collect()` too there? When I print the `gc.collect()` in each iteration, it prints 0, which means there is no more garbage, right?

Comment: No need to keep the `gc.collect()` it was just an experiment.

Comment: @tdelaney okay, I am running the program again now. I'll report back what happens. Hopefully it won't crash again at 8GB.

Comment: Does memory usage of the program creep up steadily til it crashes? If not, it may be a question of chunk sizing. Maybe 50000 items or fewer at a time. I don't think it'll matter much in processing time. You could even fall back to the `csv` module and do the conversion line by line.

Comment: The program just runs until it finished, and now I have got the 13.5 GB of file. Wow, thank you very much @tdelaney! Never would have guessed the `del chunk` would help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general syntax of a `for` loop is

```
for target in expression:
    do all the things
```

Python will evaluate the expression to an object and only when that is complete, it will assign the object to the target variable. That means that any object already in `target` is not deleted until after its replacement has been built.

That's not a big deal unless the object being created is large. That's the case here. The about-to-be deleleted chunk is in memory when the new one is created, effectively doubling the impact on memory. The solution is to manually delete the target in the loop before returning for more.

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv(fname, chunksize=chunksize,sep='|',error_bad_lines=False):

    chunk['col1'] = chunk['col1'].apply(process1)
    chunk['col2'] = chunk['col2'].apply(process2)

    if c == 0:
        chunk.to_csv("result/result.csv", index=False)
    else:
        chunk.to_csv('result/result.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
    del chunk # destroy dataframe before next loop to conserve memory.    
    if c%10==0:
        print(c)
    c+=1
```